# Finding volume of a solid

Tags: integration, volume

Okay so this question comes in two parts and the second part of the question doesn't make any sense to me.

Let $R$ be the region in the first quadrant that lives between the curves $f(x) = x^2$ and
$g(x)=\sqrt{x}$

$(a)$ Sketch $R$ and determine its $area$.

I did this getting $\frac13$ as my area

$(b)$ Now suppose that $R$ is the base of a solid. For this solid, each cross section perpendicular to the $x-axis$ is a square. Find the $volume$ of this solid.

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks something like this...

So the length of the square at $x$ is $h=\sqrt{x}-x^2$, and the area is $A=h^2$. Now integrate $A\,\mathrm{d}x$ along $x$ to find the volume.

[image]

Comment: so am i to find the volume of the pink area or the squares

Comment: @Panthy I've updated my answer. The pink is just the area $R$ that you've already found. The dashed lines (combined with the outline of $R$) form the volume.

Comment: I did it getting 9/70 as my answer... is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I also get 9/70.

Comment: @Panthy And in case you've yet to discover this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28sqrt%28x%29-x%5E2%29%5E2+dx+from+0+to+1